# How to align two images side by side if one label has more lines

Tags: graphics, captions, vertical-alignment, minipage

I have two same sized images and want them side by side with a caption under them.

My code looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3}
    \caption{label1}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{4}
    \caption{label2}
  \label{fig:test2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

which works fine until one of the labels has 2 lines, than it looks like this:

[image]

and I woud like to prevent it to look something like this:

[image]

How can it be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the `[t]` position specifier for both `minipage` environments.

A separate observation: All three `\centering` instructions are redundant.

If you want a bit of separation between the `minipage` environments, specify their widths as `0.475\textwidth` instead of `0.5\textwidth` -- and maximize their horizontal separation by inserting an `\hfill` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth} % not "0.5\textwidth"
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3}
    \caption{label1}
    \label{fig:test1}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % <-- new
\begin{minipage}[t]{.475\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{4}
    \caption{label2 is quite a bit longer than label 1}
    \label{fig:test2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: perfect! thanks a lot, also for the additional comments, the space between the two figures was another issue I was going to look up. so you killed two birds with one stone. which is great. thanks again.