# Aligning two separate tikz figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, alignment, geogebra

I have two figures that I created using GeoGebra. I exported their PGF/TikZ code. Now I have two files: shape1.tex and shape2.tex

```
\begin{figure}
   \centering

   \scalebox{0.80}{\input{shape1}} 
   \scalebox{0.20}{\input{shape2}}

 \caption{Here is shape1 and shape 2}
\end{figure}
```

I used `\scalebox` to make sure they fit in the page. Now, the issue is their height are not the same. And, the above code places the shapes just above the caption. However, I want them to be horizontally aligned from their center. Any ideas how can I do that?

Comment: welcome-- the input files would behave as an image and so I think the following code should succeed -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369455/197451

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to align two images side by side if one label has more lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369453/how-to-align-two-images-side-by-side-if-one-label-has-more-lines)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: At least show us the output of the current result so we can see your problem, too. (For that please edit your question.)